# What is the maximum size of temp tablespace in oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Trying to execute the next command

```
SELECT * FROM dba_temp_free_space
```

I am getting an error:

> Error: ORA-01652: unable to extent temp segment by 128 in tablespace temp

and there are 32 GB of space is free, but when I ran a procedure I've got an error. When I check autoextending of the temp tablespace, it says YES..

What should I do to get maximum size of temp tablespace?

Comment: this is the only error i am getting ": Error: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP"

Comment: This generally indicates a procedure or report that is doing a lot of work sorting or joining.  Unless you are dealing with tables with millions of rows poor or inefficient queries are often the cause

Comment: @kevinsky can you please tell me the maximum size of temp table space?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are focusing on a solution, not the problem. A 32 GB tablespace should be adequate for most operations in a small OLTP database.  You have not told us much about what is running when you get the error so I can only supply some diagnostics and test queries.  The [maximum size of any tablespace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits002.htm#i287915) could be as much as 128 Terabyte or as small as 32 Terabyte with 8k block size.

Try this query while your problem object is running:

```
select TABLESPACE_NAME, BYTES_USED, BYTES_FREE from V$TEMP_SPACE_HEADER;
```

If you cannot change the problem object you can create a [temporary tablespace group](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Temporary_tablespace_group) and add multiple temporary tablespaces to it.

Be sure to check what temporary tablespace the user who is running the object is using with a command like this:

```
ALTER USER scott TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
```